# Wordpress how to sort posts according to Custom Field

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I tried all solutions given on this site or other websites but did not find success in sorting posts according to custom field payment package. I tried below code

```
$args = array( 'meta_key'=>'et_payment_package','meta_key'=>693 );

// Variable to call WP_Query.

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

    // Start the Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_excerpt();
    // End the Loop
    endwhile;
else:

// If no posts match this query, output this text.
    _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' );
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

It shows

> Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Your query arguments are wrong. You have `meta_key` twice. Try with

```
$args = array( 'meta_key'=>'et_payment_package', 'meta_value'=>693 );
```

And try to specify the post type.

For instance:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'meta_key'   => 'et_payment_package',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'et_payment_package',
            'value'   => '693',
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I don't have all the details (post type etc), but this is how you'd go about it. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am sorry by mistake meta_key is typed in place of meta_value.Thank You for Your Answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response but it is not working it does not show error message but there are no changes in posts order .Actually i want to show posts according to package selected like free,featured etc.

Comment: Can you add more info in your post - what custom post type this is, is it a plugin or theme? Woocommerce or?

Comment: I am using classified engine theme.